# Styling descendent element in slotted element

Tags: css, web-component, shadow-dom, native-web-component

Is it possible to select descendent element in slotted element?

Example like this:

```
::slotted(div p) {
        color: blue;
    }

<div><p>test</p><div>
```

It doesn't work

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49268817/slot-selector-limit-in-webcomponent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can only select top-level nodes with `::slotted()`.

The selector inside ::slotted() can only be a [*compound selector*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#compound), so `div p` is not a valid one.

According to [Hayato Ito](https://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#v1_8) :

> The reason of this restriction is to make a selector style-engine friendly, in terms of performance.

See [the styling example](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#stylinglightdom) in the Shadow Dom v1 presentation.