# slot selector limit in web component

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, native-web-component

`slot` is good to make a reusable web component, however, it has a limit so far. What I faced is the style problem. You just can't define the style inside a component, even you know what the inject content's structure would be.

Details found from my post in github [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/745)

I write a component, and try to inject content through `slot` from the outside and try to add style to the specific content in the component's shadow root.
[Demo](https://codepen.io/minzojian/pen/MVgxgj)

HTML file

```
  <my-navbar>
    <ul>
      <li>link1</li>
      <li>link2</li>
      <li>link3</li>
      </ul>
  </my-navbar>
```

JS file

```
customElements.define('my-navbar', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const sr = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    sr.innerHTML = `
      <style>
      /*worked*/
      ::slotted(ul)
      {
        color:green;
      }
      /*
      Suppose I know the outside content is "ul li", and I directly define the 
      style after they injected into component's slot. However, it just doesn't 
      work because the slotted selector is just a compound selector. It can only 
      affect the first layer 'ul'. It can't affect the child dom 'li' */
      ::slotted(ul li)
      {
        color:red;
      }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }
});
```

However, it just doesn't work directly because you just can't use a complex selector for **::slot(simple_selector)** 
[Reason](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/331)

I found an indirect solution, and that's to re-append the outside content into the slots inside the component's shadow root.
[Demo](https://codepen.io/minzojian/pen/RMWzxj)

HTML file

```
  <my-navbar>
    <!--a dom defined a slot property-->
    <ul slot='t'>
      <li>link1</li>
      <li>link2</li>
      <li>link3</li>
      </ul>
    <!--A dom not define slot property-->
    <span>1234</span>
  </my-navbar>
```

JS file

```
customElements.define('my-navbar', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const sr = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    sr.innerHTML = `
      <style>
      ul li
      {
        color:red;
      }
      </style>
      <slot name='t'></slot>
      <slot ></slot>
    `;
    // Do something later...
    setTimeout(this.appendOutsideSlotContentIntoInsideSlot.bind(this), 1000)
  }

    appendOutsideSlotContentIntoInsideSlot()
  {

    // Insert outside dom element which has define slot property into the specify slot inside the shadow root
    debugger;
     for (let objIndex=0;objIndex<this.children.length;) 
     {
        var obj=this.children[objIndex];
        if(obj.slot){
          var slot=this.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot[name='+obj.slot+']');
          if(slot)
          {
              slot.appendChild(obj);
              continue;
           }
       }
       objIndex++;
    }


    // Insert the rest dom which has not define slot property values into the anonymous slot
    var defaultSlot=Array.prototype.slice.call(this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('slot')).filter(function(el){ return !el.name})[0];

    debugger;
    if(defaultSlot)
      {
         while (this.children.length>0) 
        {
          defaultSlot.appendChild(this.children[0])

        }

      }
  }
});
```

Well, it works for the contents which have defined the slot property, but doesn't work again with content that has no slot property.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389483/styling-descendent-element-in-slotted-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the exception of a few inheritable rules the contents of the slot are not supposed to be directly affected by your component's shadow CSS. They are designed to allow the CSS outside of your component to be in control.

That is by design.

This is similar to the protection given to elements within the shadow DOM not being affected by external CSS.

Read the section **Styling distributed nodes** found here:  https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#stylinglightdom

You are only allowed to change CSS rules for the top level elements inside the slot. And you are even limited to what you can do to that. All child elements are controlled by the CSS outside of the shadow DOM.

In the example below you will see that we can change the color and background color of the top level elements, or the `<ul>` tags:

```js
customElements.define('my-navbar', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const sr = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    sr.innerHTML = `
      <style>
      ::slotted(ul)
      {
        color: blue;
      }
      
      ::slotted(.bold) {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #222;
        color: #FFF;
      }
      
      ::slotted(.italic) {
        font-style: italic;
        background-color: #AAA;
        color: #000;
      }

      ::slotted(*)
      {
        color: red;
      }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }
});
```

```html
<my-navbar>
  <ul class="bold">
    <li>link1</li>
    <li class="italic">link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="italic">
    <li>link1</li>
    <li class="bold">link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
  </ul>
</my-navbar>
```

In the example above, the only reason the text is red and not blue is because `::slotted(*)` affects just the two `<ul>`, has the same specificity as `::slotted(ul)` and is placed after `::slotted(ul)`. The color is inherited by the `<li>` tags because that is how CSS works.

The background colors only affect the `<ul>` tags based on their classes and not the `<li>` tags with identical classes.

In the example below, the `<li>` color and background-color are controlled by the CSS outside the shadow DOM. The external rules act as if they are more specific then the shadow DOM rules even though the shadow DOM rules included both a `tag` and a `class` selector (`ul.bold`).

Again, this is by design.

```js
customElements.define('my-navbar', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    const sr = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    sr.innerHTML = `
      <style>
      ::slotted(ul)
      {
        color: blue;
      }
      
      ::slotted(ul.bold) {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #222;
        color: #FFF;
      }
      
      ::slotted(ul.italic) {
        font-style: italic;
        background-color: #AAA;
        color: #000;
      }

      ::slotted(*)
      {
        color: red;
      }
      </style>
      <slot></slot>
    `;
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  color: #555;
  backgroung-color: #ddd;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FF0;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
  background-color: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<my-navbar>
  <ul class="bold">
    <li>link1</li>
    <li class="italic">link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="italic">
    <li>link1</li>
    <li class="bold">link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
  </ul>
</my-navbar>
```

You will note that the background colors of the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags are set based on the external classes of `bold` and `italic`.

If you want to use a `<slot>` the you agree that the developer using your component has the override power for anything that is placed into the slot.

If you don't want the user to have that kind of control then the only way to prevent it is to move the component's children into the component's shadow DOM.

But be careful when you do it.

According to the rules of [Web Component constructors](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-element-conformance) you can not access or change the children of a component while in the constructor.

But you have to remember that the `connectedCallback` is called *every time* the component is inserted into the DOM. So if the developer removes and then re-appends your component then the `connectedCallback` will be called again. So you have to add a gate to prevent it from getting called twice.

Also you might want to add a [`MutationObserver`](http://devdocs.io/dom/mutationobserver) to see when the user changes the children of your components.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation!  

you give me a hint, so what my next step is just split the component's default css and js,and loaded outside,with the contents injected into slot outside